Flutter: how to configure Firebase AppCheck for development environment
I am trying to implement firebase functions into my Flutter app and I have issues with AppCheck.
Without appcheck, when trying to invoke a callable cloud function from Flutter, it fails, saying that appcheck is not installed.
Once I installed and configured it (configured AppCheck on Firebase for my flutter app, added debug keys), I always get:

Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed

As far as I understand, I need to configure a custom App Provider if I am not launching the app from the version downloaded from Play Store. This makes development annoying and time consuming.
Is there any way to test my functions without AppCheck, before launching the app on the play store?
I also tried calling the functions via Postman and on it works. Calling from Flutter doesn't
Calling the firebase functions at :
HttpsCallable callable =  FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: FIREBASE_FUNCTIONS_REGION).httpsCallable('myFunction');

I initiated the appcheck as following:
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
  );


Please edit the question to show the minimal complete reproducible example code that doesn't work the way you expect.  It's not clear what you mean by "when trying to call a function from Flutter".  We should be able to copy your code and instructions and observe the same result.

What I'm reading here is that you understand that the documentation is telling you to configure a custom App Provider for your situation, but you're unwilling to do so, and you think there is an easier way?  Seems to me that the documentation would show you the easier way, if it existed. I will point out that the whole reason App Check exists is to make it hard to invoke your function without the proper authorization, and the custom provider is the thing you need to do to create that authorization for yourself.
